# Need a script that takes results from google spreadsheet dropdown list and send them to a specified e-mail in one of the cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Been searching around on how to do this for 7 hours now but i can't find something that specifically work on that new google script thing, i am not a programmer i am an Business IT student and during my college day i worked on net beans and used commands like request.getParameter with my dropdown lists but i cant get anything of that to work with google scripts so it would be really helpful if someone here would give me an example on something simple so i can start building on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Open the script editor and paste this in there

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      address = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue(),
      msg = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
  MailApp.sendEmail(address, "data", msg);
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('Email')
       .addItem('send mail', 'sendEmail')
       .addToUi(); 
}
```

Then close and reopen the spreadsheet. A new menu should appear that let's you send an email. It takes the address from A1 and the message to send from B1.